# Is there a multi-protocol chat client that doesn't require a separate account?

Tags: instant-messaging, chat

I use Pidgin on all my desktop computers because it's completely cross-platform (even Linux) and really like it. Unfortunately they don't have a mobile app. Is there a mobile chat client that allows you to add accounts from multiple protocols (AIM, GTalk, MSN, ICQ, etc.) and DOESN'T require you to create a separate account for their service first? I've tried Trillian and IMO, but both want me to create an account for their service before I can add my other accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IM apps that don't require an additional account tend to be few and far between on Android (in my experience, anyway), but so far I've seen two:

- [eBuddy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebuddy.android) - This does have an associated "eBudy ID" account that you can register for, but you're *not* required to do so in order to use other protocols.
- IM+ ([free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.shapeservices.impluslite), [pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.shapeservices.implusfull)) - Same as eBuddy above. Another potential selling point is that the tablet interface is much nicer, IMHO.

Comment: IM+ looks good; didn't ask me to create a new account or ID. Will use the free version for a few days and if there are no issues will buy the pro version. Thanks.

Comment: E Buddy as you describe it no longer exists. It's now just another single protocol non standard chat program just like the rest.